# MySQL: Select rows with max column value and corresponded datetime grouped by another column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

My table is

```
IP  HITS    DATETIME
ip1 90      2016-09-10 01:15:37
ip2 13      2016-09-10 04:16:41
ip3 14      2016-09-10 05:17:41
ip2 12      2016-09-10 07:18:42
ip3 45      2016-09-10 09:19:42
ip1 88      2016-09-10 13:20:43
ip2 15      2016-09-10 15:21:43
ip3 26      2016-09-10 18:22:44
```

the result is

```
IP  HITS    DATETIME
ip1 90      2016-09-10 01:15:37
ip2 15      2016-09-10 15:21:43
ip3 45      2016-09-10 09:19:42
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594465/group-wise-maximum-of-a-certain-column and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211479/groupwise-maximum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `Correlated sub-query`

```
select * from yourtable a
where hits = (select max(hits) from yourtable b where a.IP = b.IP)
```

Another way using `JOIN`

```
SELECT a.IP,a.HITS,a.DATETIME
FROM   yourtable a 
       JOIN (SELECT Max(hits) AS max_hits, 
                    ip 
             FROM   yourtable 
             GROUP  BY ip) b 
         ON a.ip = b.ip 
            AND b.max_hits = a.hits
```